# Can we sync 2 highcharts drilldown so that if one drilldown is clicked, the other charts with the same id will drilldown accordingly?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Here are two different highcharts with drilldown datas. 
Can we sync the highcharts so that if the first drilldown 'type1' is clicked, other charts with 'type1' also drilldowns??

```
$('#drilldown-1').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: [{
            name: 'type1',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'type-1'
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'type-1',
            data: [
                ['type1.1', 4],
                ['type1.2', 2],
                ['type1.3', 1],
                ['type1.4', 2],
                ['type1.5', 1]
            ]
        }]
    }
}]
$('#drilldown-2').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: [{
            name: 'type1',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'type-1'
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'type-1',
            data: [
                ['type1.11', 8],
                ['type1.12', 4],
                ['type1.13', 16],
                ['type1.4', 2],
                ['type1.5', 1]
            ]
        }]
    }
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikbaidya0346/o4qmLLbq/5/

Comment: This is possible to make this kind of drilldown. Please look at this jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/c3a5prs4/ You can find here drilldown and drillup events callback functions that may help you in this case.

Comment: what if there are multiple charts and i need to drilldown/drillup the ones having common NAME/ID. in the example you shared have only one more chart and it used its index pointIndex = e.point.index;

Comment: Here you can see an example that should meet your requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/c3a5prs4/1/