# How to implement xAxis drilldown upon clicking an item on the chart?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

I'm currently working on High Charts

[image]

Currently, each chart has its own drilldown! However, what I want is to implement a multiple series drilldown. For instance, in the first container - it has 2 charts (1 line chart and a column chart) - and when I click a bar, it'll drilldown together with the line chart.

[image]

It's the same as when you click the xAxis, both the bar and line chart will drilldown. How can I do this?

Comment: I think that this topic may help you find solution for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371262/can-we-sync-2-highcharts-drilldown-so-that-if-one-drilldown-is-clicked-the-othe#comment64191788_38371262 and here you can find an example from this topic: http://jsfiddle.net/c3a5prs4/1/

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzBlachlinski! Thanks for replying! However, what I would like to have for my drilldown is that when a bar is clicked, it will drilldown to two series.

Comment: So maybe this SO topic will be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001100/highcharts-drilldown-and-combining-chart-type/38007444#38007444